# how to use an object (constructor) to call display() method in processing using java on visual studio code while importing PApplet

Tags: java, processing

i am trying to figure out how to use an object to call a methods, e.g display(), setup() inside the draw method. i am using visual studio code with a processing package imported and essentially using java to complete the process. i am also following daniel shiffman's tutorial from *the nature of code* and found myself running into trouble and its not working. i can get it to work by just calling "display();" in the draw method but i want to know how to use the object "w.display()".

my code is this:

import processing.core.PApplet;

class RandomWalker extends PApplet {

```
// walker only needs two pieces of data
// x location 
int x;
// y-location
int y;

//global var
RandomWalker w;

public void settings(){

    //establishing the size of the window
    size(640,360);
}//end method

//constructor for the walker class and its objects
RandomWalker(){

    //here we initalise the walkers objects and set the starting location
    // starting point - centre of window
    x = width /2;
    y = height/2;
   
   
}//end constructor

// a walker has two functions. 1. the walker will display itself as a white dot
public void display(){
    stroke(0);
    point(x,y);

}//end method

// directs walker to take a step
public void step(){
    //picks a random floating point number between 0 - 4
    int choice = (int)(random(4)); // chooses between 0,1,2,3

    if( choice == 0){
        x++; // move right
        // println("working");
    }//end if

    else if(choice == 1) {    

        x--; //move left
    }//end else if

    else if(choice ==2){    
        y++; // move up

    }//end else if

    else {
        y--; //move down

    }//end else
}//endmethod

//creating the setup method
public void setup(){
  
    //creating an object by calling the constructor with the new operator
    w = new RandomWalker(); // creating the walker
    background(255);

    // frameRate(190);


}//end method



//in this method, we ask the walker to take a step and draw a dot
public void draw(){
    w.step();
    w.display();
}//end method
```

}//end class

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you *need* the `draw()` method to be able to do what you want. As you may know, the `draw()` method is the main loop which Processing (or in the case the PApplet) uses, and I haven't looked the details under the hood but I already know by experience that there's more to it than meet the eyes.

So your ninja-fix - to call the `display()` method from the PApplet's `draw()` method - is, in fact, the right way to do this.

If you only ever wanted one frame, the `setup()` method would do fine, but I'm guessing here that you'll want to loop this and make it evolve through time, so please go ahead and use the `draw()` method. It's not a hack, it's the way to go!